# Urban exploration in Lisbon area, Portugal

Tags: adventure, portugal, lisbon

We need to spend some days in Lisbon (Portugal), also Sintra and the coast around that area. Are there any good places for [urbex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urban_exploration)? We know Sintra is known for its palaces and mansions (some of them abandoned), but since it's an eerie location with lots of ghost stories, I'm not sure we would enjoy that kind of urbex. But if you have any ideas...

We are interested in old architecture, industrial complexes and abandoned state buildings, universities and the like, but anything interesting is more than welcome.

I read about the roman galleries under Lisbon (and I know they open for a day every year), that would be extremely interesting but probably impossible to get in. In Portugal we already visited some abandoned hospitals, hotels, thermal facilities, even an abandoned holiday complex.

Traveling a few KMs is not an problem, we have a car or motorbike.

PS: Some of the activities related to urban exploration might be a felony (like trespassing). Always ask the owners for permission before entering a place.

Comment: See also [Outdoors.SE], which includes urbex.

Comment: @gerrit Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, from what I understood from meta, there is some disput about being on or off-topic: http://meta.outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/479/is-urban-exploration-on-topic
Also, this is actually about traveling and not so much about outdoors in general, so I guess it belongs here.

Comment: @Cthulhu I don't think gerrit was seeking to say it is an offtopic question here (to my mind, it isn't). Just that for some questions, TGO gives better answers. I'm not sure if that's the case here either though.

Answer (score 1):

In Monsanto, just next to Lisbon there are a couple of abandoned buildings.

Monsanto is a small mountain just next to Lisbon. It's considered the lung of the city and it's covered with pinetrees. Through the years many things were built here and there and than, for some reason abandoned.

One is the panoramic restaurant: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iizRWg-jNYc - It's in a very nice spot with a great view over Tagus river.

Also, there was aquaparque. A slide water park that was abandoned after an accident. I think this one is closed though, and there are plans to make a garden there. I am not sure if construction restarted.

https://www.google.nl/search?q=parque+aquatico+monsanto&biw=1855&bih=1045&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjcyPT7zIbNAhUnB8AKHf64AmEQ_AUIBigB#imgrc=8u-wmqS_TB6r1M%3A

But there are more. Just google for "abandonado serra monsanto"

A couple of kms south of Lisbon you have this building:

http://3vilas.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/palacio-rei-do-lixo.jpg

It's called tower of hell, or palace of the garbage king. It's in Coina.